# Want to create a directory with AppleScript if it doesn't already exist

Tags: applescript, posix, attachment

I wanted to automatically save attachments in Mail to my hard drive.  After lots of research I set a rule in Mail that runs the script below whenever an email with an attachment arrives.

```
use scripting additions

using terms from application "Mail"
    on perform mail action with messages messageList for rule aRule
        set destinationPath to (POSIX file "/volumes/Data/Dropbox/WORK ITEMS/Email Attachments/") as string
        tell application "Mail"
            repeat with aMessage in messageList
                repeat with anAttachment in mail attachments of aMessage
                    set senderName to (extract name from sender of aMessage)
                    set {year:y, month:m, day:d, hours:h, minutes:min} to date received of aMessage
                    set timeStamp to (d & "/" & (m as integer) & "/" & y) as string
                    set attachmentName to senderName & " - " & timeStamp & " - " & name of anAttachment
                    
                    set doSave to true
                    set originalName to name of anAttachment
                    if originalName contains "jpg" then
                        set doSave to false
                    else if originalName contains "jpeg" then
                        set doSave to false
                    else if originalName contains "gif" then
                        set doSave to false
                    else if originalName contains "png" then
                        set doSave to false
                    else if originalName contains "html" then
                        set doSave to false
                    end if
                    
                    if doSave is true then save anAttachment in file (destinationPath & attachmentName)
                    
                end repeat
            end repeat
        end tell
        
    end perform mail action with messages
end using terms from
```

This works fine. The exclusions stop the script saving logos in email signatures etc.
But this script does mean all the files are in one directory (Email Attachments).

As the script has the name of the sender what I have been trying to do is create a subdirectory in 'Email Attachments' using the sender name (bur only creating it if it doesn't exist) and then save the file as 'timestamp & name' of the attachment in that directory.

This way I will have a directory structure under 'Email Attachments' of all the sender names with their attachments in their own directory.

I have tried everything I can - and haven't succeeded (I can post my latest attempt here but would rather save my blushes!!)

Does anyone know how to amend my script to make this work???  Thank you if you have any ideas...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To test if the target *folder* exists, and if not create it, you can use the following *example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
tell application "System Events"
    if not (exists folder (destinationPath & senderName)) then
        make new folder at end of alias destinationPath with properties {name:senderName}
    end if
end tell
```

Another way to create the *folder* if it doesn't exist is:

```
do shell script "mkdir -p " & (POSIX path of destinationPath & senderName)'s quoted form
```

This will create it if it doesn't exist, and if it does it does nothing.

---

On a side note, here is a way to eliminate the `if` ... `else if` *block* of *code* you have:

```
set doSave to true
set originalName to name of anAttachment
set doNotSaveFileTypeList to {"jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png", "html"}
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "."
set fileExtension to last text item of originalName
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to ""
if the doNotSaveFileTypeList contains fileExtension then
    set doSave to false
end if
```

When the *action* is the same for all the *list items*, I like using this method as it's easier to add or remove from the *list* without having to modify the rest of the *code block*.

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted.</sub>

Comment: Thanks that's great - works a treat and creates the folder.  I also like the if/else script that will make it easier to add to.   Can you give me one more piece of help.  I am trying to edit the 'if dosave is true then save....'line to use the newly created folder and I can't get it to work.  Any ideas?  thanks

Comment: @Jonathan Hewitt, Based on the current _code_, this works for me: `if doSave is true then save anAttachment in file (destinationPath & senderName & ":" & attachmentName)` That said, I would not use `/` in the `timeStamp`, use `-` instead.

Comment: I'm not at my own computer to check this, so perhaps I'm remembering incorrectly. I don't think _SystemEvents_ tends to complain if one tries to create a new file/folder at a path that already exists.  Therefore, even without the `if...then` test, it might be fine to simply: `tell app "System Events" to make new folder with properties {name:destinationPath & senderName}` (provided the folder at `destinationPath` exists already).